# How do I parse an input string in Dart?

Tags: javascript, dart

I want to parse an input mathematical string. How do I do it in Dart (with three.dart)?

Here is the js (three.js) version:

```
zFunc = Parser.parse(zFuncText).toJSFunction( ['x','y'] );
    meshFunction = function(x, y) 
    {
        x = xRange * x + xMin;
        y = yRange * y + yMin;
        var z = zFunc(x,y); //= Math.cos(x) * Math.sqrt(y);
        if ( isNaN(z) )
            return new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0); // TODO: better fix
        else
            return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in short : "is not as simple as in JS"

**Explanation :**

if i understand well your need, you want to be able to parse string expression like :

```
String math_square_expr = "(x) => pow(x, 2)"
some_magic_func(math_squre_expr)(5) // return 25
```

but it's possible in javascript, because you have some function like 'eval()' and others thing that make easy to transform string to code.

In Dart, you don't have this kind of function. the situation is more like with Java for this case.

***You have 2 choice:***

*Build your own mathematical parser* -> it's not cool, but if you need only little stuff it's possible

*Use Js to do the job* -> another solution is to use Javascript to create the function, but executed with dart. here a example :

```
import 'dart:js';

void main() {
  String function = "var f = function(x, y) { return x*x + y; }";
  JsObject functionJs = context.callMethod("eval", [function]);
  print(functionJs);
  print(context.callMethod("f", [5, 2]));
}
```

**explanation:**

```
String function = "var f = function(x, y) { return x*x + y; }";
```

First i create a variable named function to simulate user input, it need to be replace by a call or other thing to get user input.
Important thing: i create a javascript function that i store in a javascript variable. This will create a global javascript symbol named f.

```
JsObject functionJs = context.callMethod("eval", [function]);
```

Here i call a javascript function "eval" to dynamic evaluate the string previously create. after this operation my global JS context will contain a variable named f, with a function store in it.

```
print(context.callMethod("f", [5, 2]));
```

Know than my function is created and i can access on it, i call my function store in f, with my 2 parameters (x=5, y=2) and i display the result.

***Note:*** becareful the to named of the JS variable that you will store your function. take a unused named.

Comment: The first line is juste a example of an input string. You can replace it by a user input

Comment: I have explained my code in the answer :) (just edited)

Comment: Thank you very much. What does the double.parse() in Dart do? I found it in the Docs and I was wondering if it was something similar to 'eval'.

Comment: Also, how do I use/access the variables 'x' and 'y' from the function?

Comment: double.parse() transform a input string into a double. It's the function that use 'x' and 'y', to modify the behavior you need to modify the core of the function ('return x*x+y' is just a example). here x=5 and y=2, so if you want to change you just change the parameter pass to 'context.callMethod("f", [x, y])' call

Comment: Yes, but how do I use 'x' and 'y' again someplace else? Thanks again!